# Microsoft domain deliverability issues

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability

Does anyone have the same occurrence where Marketing Cloud is not delivering emails to microsoft domains i.e @live, @hotmail, @outlook?

If so is there a particular issue and can it be solved?

I can confirm that i have sent emails in various manners, template testers, developer testing campaign sends, subscriber opt in / welcome emails and they do not get through.

Other domains are fine as per the send report below. 
We have used Marketing Cloud for close to 2-3 months and have warmed up our IP properly.

[image: Email Send Report]

Answer (score 1):

As per the report given, there is no considerable instance found that emails were not delivered.

If you see the bounce rate, it is less than 1%. Some have open rate greater than 0%. This is likely a chance that all of the email sents to Microsoft domain are filtered out by server and put in spam box of the email owner.

Please check with Microsoft spam filtering requirements as well as security/authentication mechanism they expect from email sender.